# Python - PySimpleGUI - Can't select Calendar Input

Tags: python, calendar, pysimplegui

I am making a very simple interface that requires only three fields.
The first one is a text input to introduce the name of a Team, the second one to choose my Team name and the third is a calendar input to introduce a date.

For that I am using the below code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Interface', key='-TXT-')]
      , [sg.Text('Team ID', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(size=(45, 1), key='-team_value-')]
      , [sg.Text('Team Name', size=(15, 1),), sg.InputText(size=(45, 1), key='-team_name_value-')]
      , [sg.Input(key='-IN4-', size=(20,1)), sg.CalendarButton('Calendar',  target='-IN4-', default_date_m_d_y=(1,None,2020), )]
      , [sg.Button('Introduce'), sg.Button('Search'), sg.Button('End'), sg.Button('Date Popup'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]

window = sg.Window('window', layout)

text_elem = window['-TXT-']

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
    elif event == 'Date Popup':
        sg.popup('You chose:', sg.popup_get_date())

window.close()
```

However, when I open my Calendar date I am not able to select any date, it just opens the calendar and stays static, and it doesn't allow me to choose any date.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Update to latest version of PySimpleGUI, also upgrade PySimpleGUI from GitHub by `sg.main()` if necessary.

Comment: Have the same issue in PySimpleGUI v4.34.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is to not use the default theme. Set a new theme above your 'layout' declaration:

```
sg.theme("Dark Blue 3")
layout = [...]
```

Alternatively you can create your own theme. The calendar uses the "TEXT" color to color the date numbers and to highlight the first row of the calendar.

```
my_new_theme = {'BACKGROUND': '#ececec',
                'TEXT': 'black',
                'INPUT': 'white',
                'TEXT_INPUT': 'black',
                'SCROLL': 'white',
                'BUTTON': ('black', 'white'),
                'PROGRESS': ('#0091ff', '#D0D0D0'),
                'BORDER': 1,
                'SLIDER_DEPTH': 0,
                'PROGRESS_DEPTH': 0}

sg.theme_add_new('my_custom_theme', my_new_theme)
sg.theme('my_custom_theme')
layout = [...]
```

Comment: The default theme wouldn't be what causes this.

Comment: @MikefromPSG Had the same issue, and changing theme did help. The problem would appear only when I built executable with PyInstaller. When running program from terminal then calendar works fine with default theme.

Comment: For onyone stumbling on this answer, there's a thread for this issue https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/3372